Fourier transformation and estimation
I'm studying quantum mechanics and want to know about Laplacian, which often appears in equations of quantum mechanics.
Here, I think Laplacian $\Delta$ as a operator whose domain is $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ ($d$ is a natural number).
Let $\varphi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and its Fourie transform be $\hat{\varphi}$.
I'd like to show, for $d\leq3$ and arbitrary $a >0$ there exists $b$ such that
$$\|\hat{\varphi}\|_1\leq a\|\Delta\varphi\|_2+b\|\varphi\|_2$$
I think I can use the following scaling property.
Let $\varphi_r(x)=\varphi(r^{-1}x)$. Then $\hat{\varphi_r}(k)= |r|^d\hat{\varphi}(rk)$ and $\|\hat{\varphi_r}\|_2=\|\hat{\varphi}\|_2$.
I arrive at my goal if I can show following from the property,
$$\|\hat{\varphi}\|_2\leq cr^{\frac{d-4}{2}}\||k|^2\hat{\varphi}\|_2+cr^{\frac{d}{2}}\|\hat{\varphi}\|_2,$$
with a constant $c$ independent of $r$.
Could you give me advice or good reference? Thanks in advance.

Let $c_1$ denote the volume of $\{k\in \mathbb{R}^d\,:\,|k|\le 1\}.$ For $r>0$ we have
$$\|\widehat{\varphi}\|_1=\int\limits_{|k|\le r}|\widehat{\varphi}(k)|\,dk+ \int\limits_{|k|> r}|\widehat{\varphi}(k)|\,dk\\ \overset{Cauchy-Schwarz}{\le} c_1^{1/2}r^{d/2}\|\widehat{\varphi}\|_2+\int\limits_{|k|> r}|\widehat{\varphi}(k)|\,dk\\
=  c_1^{1/2}r^{d/2}\|{\varphi}\|_2+\int\limits_{|k|> r} |k|^{-2}|k|^2{|\widehat{\varphi}(k)|}\,dk\\
\overset{Cauchy-Schwarz}{\le} c_1^{1/2}r^{d/2}\|{\varphi}\|_2+\left (\int\limits_{|k|>r}|k|^{-4}\,dk\right )^{1/2}\left (\int\limits_{|k|>r}|k|^{4}|\widehat{\varphi}(k)|^2\,dk\right )^{1/2}\\ =   c_1^{1/2}r^{d/2}\|{\varphi}\|_2+r^{d/2-2}\left (\int\limits_{|u|>1}|u|^{-4}\,du\right )^{1/2}\left (\int\limits_{|k|>r}|k|^{4}|\widehat{\varphi}(k)|^2\,dk\right )^{1/2}\\ \le c_1^{1/2}r^{d/2}\|{\varphi}\|_2+c_2r^{d/2-2}\|\Delta\varphi\|_2 $$
where $c_2=(\int\limits_{|u|>1}|u|^{-4}\,du )^{1/2}.$
Since $c_2<\infty$ and $d/2-2<0$ the answer is affirmative.

It's really kind and perfect answer!! Thank you very much for taking you time! I finally understood!
